# Server side file validation

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make file upload to server by form:

```
<form action="send_valid.php" method="POST" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="pdf" id="pdf" accept="application/pdf"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Wyślij">
    </form>
```

and I want to allow user to send only **pdf files** of a **max size 10Mb**.

My php configuration for uploads is:

```
file_uploads = On  
upload_tmp_dir = "E:\Xampp\tmp"  
upload_max_filesize = 11M  
max_file_uploads = 20  
post_max_size = 12M
```

To check file size I use:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  var_dump($_FILES);
  if(extract($_FILES)){
    if($pdf['size']>10000000){
      echo "File size is too large!";
    }
  }
```

Now I want to show user an error (for now) with **echo** when file is too big. It works fine if it is lower than 10Mb (even the code above works when I change size to 1Mb and file is larger then it will display **echo**), but for files of 10Mb and above it produces that error:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 11450416 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
array(0) { }
```

I don't have any clue why it shows it exceeds **8Mb** since in configs I couldn't find 8Mb anywhere.

Where can be the problem? Is there a way to catch an upload that exceeds configuration setting to not show user the php server error?

And if I want to make file validation does **above method** and checking file extension with for examle:

```
$ext = pathinfo($_POST['pdf'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

is it enough? Any insight on file validation would be really helpful.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the values of `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in your php configuration file.

Note that the values are measured in bytes.

### Reference

- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size
- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

Comment: But I updated the values to 11M = 11Mb (right?) for upload_max_filesize and 12M for post_max_size.

Comment: What do you find as the entry for both when you call `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Sorry! You were right. I didn't update the values the stayed default. But what about files that will exceed max value? I think it will still output the server **Warning**

Answer (score 1):

Probably this

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '512M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '512M');
```

Change 512 to any of you want.

Comment: I can't find lines that match with your answer. Should I add them? If so, where?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I added it in the beginning of my file check and it returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code before move_uploaded_file function

```
 if($_FILES['pdf']['size']>10000000) {
        exit("File size is too large!");
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: This above won't work (or maybe I'm doing sth wrong) because $_FILES is an array and in it is array "pdf". So this will output following error: Notice: Undefined index: pdf in

Comment: No it will not show you any index error and you must keep the file name="pdf". Thanks

Comment: I used your code suggestion and with a file upload of 11Mb it outputs following errors: Warning: 
POST Content-Length of 11450413 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Undefined index: pdf in E:\Xampp\htdocs\php\bazy_danych\obiektowe\my\send_valid.php on line 2

Comment: set the post size post_max_size = 1000M; please keep the post and file size same.